# How Task Parallel Library performs load balancing?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, multicore, multitasking

We all know that in order to really perform asynchronous operations, our machine have to have multiple cores that each one of them will run its' own thread that will execute its' task.

Lets start with an example in which we have a **quad core cpu** and **4 tasks**. In order to run our four tasks in real parallelism using **C#** we will have to create and run 4 tasks separately like so:

```cs
public static void Main()
{    
   // Define and run the tasks.
   Task[] tasks = {
      Task.Run( () => WorkA() ),
      Task.Run( () => WorkB() ),
      Task.Run( () => WorkC() ),
      Task.Run( () => WorkD() )
   }

   Task.WaitAll(tasks);
}
```

In this example **TPL** will supply each task with a thread from the **ThreadPool** and run each thread in a different processor if possible. (I hope I am right)

**The scenario:**

Lets say that we have **quad core cpu** and **6 tasks** and we wrote the following code:

```cs
public static void Main()
{    
   // Define and run the tasks.
   Task[] tasks = {
      Task.Run( () => WorkA() ),
      Task.Run( () => WorkB() ),
      Task.Run( () => WorkC() ),
      Task.Run( () => WorkD() ),
      Task.Run( () => WorkE() ),
      Task.Run( () => WorkF() )
   }

   Task.WaitAll(tasks);
}
```

Will **TPL** know what is the best sufficient amount of threads and schedule the tasks among them? (considering the cores' states and the tasks' load differences)

for example:

- Total of 3 threads - 2 tasks per thread. (Lets say one core is busy)
- Total of 4 threads - 3 threads - 1 task per thread and 3 tasks for the last 
  one.
- Total of 6 threads - 1 task per thread.

How does TPL perform load balancing? What TPL takes in consideration in order to provide the best load balancing..

Comment: The task scheduler will never **know** what is the best strategy. And when he knows it is too late because the work is done. So there is a lot of guessing, measuring the cpu cores workload and the task creation options. Thats all - there is no future sight or any kind of magic built in

Comment: The task scheduler is a general tool trying to get the work done as fast as it is in general possible without knowing what kind of job has to be done. If you know your work and load better you should build your own specialized thread driven job worker to get the last percent of performance :o)

Comment: To expand on Sir Rufo’s valid points is that Threads have a high cost to start due to the per thread overhead for the explicitly created thread.  Using the built in Task Thread pool allows for many smaller shorter tasks to be created while re-using the built in Thread pool and frees your code from managing a thread pool and scheduling and syncing etc.    So if you have 1000 unrelated tasks use the built in Thread pool.   If you have 5 independent groups of 200 related operations use your own pool of 5 threads.

Answer (score 1):

> Will TPL know what is the best sufficient amount of threads and
>   schedule the tasks among them?

No. It's more complicated then you think:

`Task.Run()` adds a Task to the global queue. Suppose you already have 4 idle threads in your pool, then they will try to take Tasks from the global queue, an operation that involves synchronization and locks. Depends on the workload of each Task, it could be more efficient to let just one or two threads to handle all the tasks. And what if there is only one thread in the pool? Creating 3 more threads might be more expensive then the execution of the Tasks by the single thread. That information is not available during runtime, of course.